# How to display an array of images from the firestore database in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

hello how to show an array of images from the firestore database in react native? i tried this but no images are showing

```
{this.props.user.map((images)=>{
return (
  <View>
    <Image style={ {width: 350, height: 300}} source={{uri: images.photos}} />
  </View>
);
})}
```

i am getting this warning at the bottom of the screen in yellow

''Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'ForwardRef(image)' ''

Comment: What is the path value of the image?

Comment: My meaning is the actual value.

Comment: it is a path to images urls @hongdevelop

Comment: I'm mean real path ex) `http://www.exam.com/exam.png`

Comment: ok @hongdevelop here's the path https://picsum.photos/id/1001/5616/3744, https://picsum.photos/id/1002/4312/2868

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is you are not giving the proper path of the image in source uri. Can you first check in postman that what kind of data type is images.photos? And if it's not an url for the image, react native won't render. Always store your images as images.photos.uri for easy clarification. And by the way if images.photos is an array of url, then react Native won't render. You need to pass each uri to each  image tag, and what you can do is iterate images in another map function so that each image is iterated.

Comment: ok the images.photos is an array of url could you please show me an example on how to do this '' pass each uri to each image tag, and what you can do is iterate images in another map function so that each image is iterated. ''  @GauravRoy

Comment: hey @E.pross , PFB the solution for this , and im assuming you have an array of urls in photos so im directly passing it as the uri source, and if its in an object you can replace image inside uri with image.uri in source={{uri: mage.uri}} : do upvote if you think its correct so that it can help others 
```{this.props.user.map((images)=>{
  images.photos.map((image) =>{
    return (
      <View>
        <Image style={ {width: 350, height: 300}} source={{uri: image}} />
      </View>
    );
  })
  
  })}```

Comment: hi @GauravRoy thanks i tried your solution it works but the images still not showing, i console log image and all the images url are being console log but it isn't showing i the image tag

Comment: can you send me the whole images.photos  data object?

Comment: hi @GauravRoy the data is on firestore database and this is the structure i am trying to show the photos array here: ` Object {
   
    "age": 9,
    "books": Array [ 1, 3, ],
    "city": "NYC",
    "name": "Marry",
    "photos": Array [
      "https://picsum.photos/id/1001/5616/3744",
      "https://picsum.photos/id/1002/4312/2868",
      "https://picsum.photos/id/1003/1181/1772",
    ],

  }  `